# Access to this blocks Jenkins Pipelines script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following test Groovy script to be added as `vars` to `workflow-libs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

this.test = false

def setTest(boolean test) { this.test = test }

def getTest() { this.test }

def log(level, msg) {
    echo "[${level}] ${msg}"
}

def call(msg) {
    if (this.test) log('TEST', msg)
}
```

I place this script under `workflow-libs/vars/test.groovy`.

When I execute the following pipeline:

```
node {
  test 'foo'
}
```

the process never finishes, but if I remove the `if (this.test)` then it finishes normally, though I conclude that there is an issue accessing `this` object?

Anyone faced a similar behavior?

Jenkins is the latest version at time 1.651.3.

Answer (score 2):

In groovy `this.test` calls the auto generated or existing getter `getTest()` ([doc](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_getters_and_setters)). Your script simply stuck into infinite recursion.

[Here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_direct_field_access_operator) is explained how to directly access fields in groovy though I am not sure it will work in Pipelines.

Alternatively you can use just a script-wide variable `test` instead of `this.test`. Or rename `this.test` into something different from accessor methods' names like `this._test`.

Comment: Thanks @izzeki your hint eventually led me to dig more the object and found out that the actual parameter is located under this.binding.variables which is a Map object I will put the finding as an answer if someone is interested or can provide a better solution

Comment: Sure @tbo. You might find it useful as well to know that Binding is not Serializable but it has `Map getVariables()` method.

Answer (score 0):

finally I managed to over pass this issue by using the `binding` object of `this` as follows:

```
def enableTest(enable = true) {
    // this goes to binding variables
    this.test = enable }
```

to use the variable set (if it is set!)

```
if (this.binding.variables['test'] && this.test) {
  // do something usefull
}
```

Hope it helps